# DirectX not showing up in references

Tags: c#, directx

I just installed the DirectX SDK but when I try to add a reference to it, it isnt showing up in my list. So, I need to know either how to get all the DX references added to the list or which DLL I need to browse for. I'm trying to get Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback

Comment: DirectX is not a managed library (you can't add a reference to it). Are you maybe looking for [SharpDX](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/)?

Comment: Umm... So what are they using on this site? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/111181-adding-video-to-an-application/

Comment: "DirectX for Managed Code", apparently. I stand corrected. Still, [it seems to be deprecated](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/17641/6084). Maybe that's why it's not showing up in the reference browse dialog? See if you can find the DLL manually on your hard drive...

Comment: Yeah, i found the dll's.. i just dont know which one i need "d3d9d.dll" "D3D10Ref.DLL" "D3D10SDKLayers.DLL" "D3D11Ref.dll" "D3D11SDKLayers.dll" "D3DCSXd_43.dll" "d3dref9.dll" "d3dx9d_33.dll" "D3dx9d_43.dll" "D3DX10d_43.dll" "D3DX11d_43.dll" "X3DAudioD1_7.dll" "XactEngineA3_7.dll" "XactEngineD3_7.dll" "XAPOFXD1_5.dll" "XAudioD2_7.dll"  -edit- meh, none of those will open anyways... well shoot.

Comment: ok i think my answer is XNA http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

Comment: All those DLLs you mentioned form part of the normal, *unmanaged* part of DirectX. I'd never heard of the managed one until today. XNA a library for making games, built on top of DX9. SharpDX (linked in my first comment) is a very nice, direct wrapper for DirectX which can be used in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, anyways, I've downloaded DirectX9 where managed code still exists and this fixed my problem. I considered using SharpDX but it had zero documentation.